# issues installing pygit2 on windows

Tags: github, pygit2

I am trying to install 
http://www.pygit2.org/install.html#installing-on-windows

As part of that I Installed in windows Cmake(Cmake-gui).
when I selected in Source code-libgit2-0.26.0 (downloaded from -https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/archive/v0.26.0.zip)

## and did configure I am getting the Error:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (PROJECT):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

```
MSBuild.exe
```

to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/....GIThub/s/libgit2-0.26.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

when I open the log I see only:

## The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64

Can you please help me how I can install pygit2 on windows?